# Applying for a Canadian ETA after previous visits without one

Tags: visas, canada, eta

When applying for a [Canadian ETA](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta.asp), the form asks this question:

> Have you previously applied to enter or remain in Canada?

I am a citizen of a [visa-exempt country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Canada#Visa_exemptions) and have visited Canada before the ETA regime was implemented.  Does such a visit count as "previously applying"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [official help](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/eta/english.pdf) for this question indicates that it is asking if you have ever applied for a *visa* to Canada.

> Select yes if, in the past, you submitted an application to come to Canada, such as a study permit, work permit or visitor visa.

If you answer Yes to this question, you'll be asked for your Unique Client Identifier, visa or permit number.

> If, in the past, you submitted an application to come to Canada such as a study permit or work permit, you will have a Unique Client Identifier (UCI).
>
> Look for this number on letters you received from Citizenship and Immigration Canada or on the immigration document that was issued. Example: study permit, work permit, or visitor visa.
>
> If you do not know what your UCI is, enter your immigration document number. Example: study permit, work permit, or visitor visa number.

You will not have such a number if you have entered Canada under a visa-exemption, further indicating that this is meant for people who applied for *visas*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39868/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-hampton-applying-for-a-canadian-eta-after-previo).

Answer (score 6):

I applied for an ETA a couple of weeks ago, and had been twice under the VWP before. I put "Yes" and left the UCI/Visa/Permit number blank. Didn't seem to matter, got an approval almost instantly.